# ruby chef recipe array &&= conditional

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I am learning ruby to write chef cookbooks. I was going through this recipe
https://github.com/sous-chefs/mongodb/blob/master/recipes/default.rb. I was stumbled at this code block.

```
conflicting_recipes.each do |recipe| 
  allow_mongodb_instance_run &&= false if node.run_context.loaded_recipe?(recipe)
end
```

I went through documentation of `&&=` but it didn't make much sense to me. Can someone please care to explain this to me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Expand the expression like this:

```
allow_mongodb_instance_run = allow_mongodb_instance_run && false
```

If `allow_mongodb_instance_run` is truthy (not `false` or `nil`), it becomes `false`.

If `allow_mongodb_instance_run` is `false` it remains `false`.

if `allow_mongodb_instance_run` is `nil`, it remains `nil`, and does not become `false`.

No I don't know why someone needs this distinction, but preserving the `nil` is the only benefit I can think of over just `allow_mongodb_instance_run = false`.

Answer (score 0):

It's a slightly awkward way to check if the node is also set up to run the older `sc-mongodb` cookbook before the two were merged back together because having both would lead to conflicts (both cookbooks trying to configure/install the same things).